# Sending e-mail fails in Joomla 2.5

Tags: apache, email, joomla, smtp, wamp

I know it's a very common problem, but none of the solutions I found worked.. I'm working in Joomla and the E-mail function doesn't seem to work anywhere. I especially need it to reset forgotten passwords.

So, when I use SMTP I get : "Failed sending email", when I use PHP mail I get "Could not instantiate mail function"

I already tried these :

- http://www.fox.ra.it/forum/13-submissions-via-email/443-could-not-instantiate-mail-function.html
- http://hattrickconsulting.ca/web-seo-social-media/joomla-could-not-instantiate-mail-function/
- http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/joomla-25/how-to/configure-email-over-smtp
- and putting extension=php_openssl.dll in php.ini of the server (didn't keep the link of where I found this one)

Nothing works, I hope someone could help me.. I'm working in local with :

> Joomla! 2.5.9
>
> Wamp server
>
> Apache 2.2.22
>
> PHP 5.4.3

Comment: If you put your site on an online host I bet it would work. Give that a try if you already have one, else set your WAMP server to **online** if it is currently **offline**

Comment: I put the Wamp online and still doesn't work. And I don't have access to an online host for now. But I hope you're right and it'll work once hosted. Thank's for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Well I finally found a solution after hours of searching, I thought I share it, it might help someone. Some WAMP configurations were needed.

Details here : http://blog.techwheels.net/send-email-from-localhost-wamp-server-using-sendmail/